# No se puede dibujar un rectángulo en el marco de la cámara con opencv android

Tags: java, android, opencv

Estoy tratando de hacer algo como esto con OpenCV en Android Studio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038059/opencv-java-draw-a-rectangle-region-on-camera-view Dibujar un rectangular la pantalla con la camara en vivo,  es el mismo trabajo. pero para mí no funciona. Estoy usando opencv para Android 3.4.10 También lo probé usando opencv 3.4.7 y 3.2.0 pero no funciona. Aquí está mi código:

```
 @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        if(mRgba!=null){
            mRgba.release();
        }
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
          
        int w = mRgba.width();
        int h = mRgba.height();

        Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, new Point(w * 1 / 3, h * 1 / 3), new Point(
                w * 2 / 3, h * 2 /  3 ), new Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 5
        );
        
        return mRgba;
    }
```

La aplicación solo muestra la imagen normal sin ningún rectángulo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé realmente por qué no funciona, por favor, chicos, si tienen alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo, se lo agradeceré. Gracias por adelantado.

PD: Estoy usando CameraBridgeViewBase ... este es un pequeño código de mi método onCreate () en mi MainActivity.java

```
cameraBridgeViewBase =(JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
        cameraBridgeViewBase.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        cameraBridgeViewBase.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
```

Comment: Lo arregle en el OnCreate tenia esto `cameraBridgeViewBase =(JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);` lo cambié a `cameraBridgeViewBase =(CameraBridgeViewBase)findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);` Esto me hizo probar en tres versiones de opencv..

Comment: Puedes responder a tu propia pregunta si deseas , así otras personas que tenga el mismo problema tendrán una respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Me auto respondo luego de haberlo solucionado.

El problema esta que al momento de mapear la vista `java_camera_view`:

```
<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:id="@+id/java_camera_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:show_fps="true" />
```

Dentro del método `onCreate()` del `MainActivity.java` se estaba haciendo casting de tipo JavaCameraView para el cameraBridgeViewBase:

```
cameraBridgeViewBase =(JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
```

La solución es hacer casting de la siguiente manera usando el mismo tipo del CameraBridgeViewBase:

```
ameraBridgeViewBase =(CameraBridgeViewBase)findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
```

y listo solucionado.

Comment: Luego de hacer esto tenemos que hacer Build->clean Build>Rebuild proyect